# Will timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: fire immediately or will it fire first time after the specified time interval?

Tags: iphone

The documentation says about timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:

> Returns a new NSTimer that, when added
>   to a run loop, will fire after a
>   specified number of seconds.

I don't fully understand this. Maybe someone can tell if it fires immediately or if the first time the selector gets called would be after the specified time interval (i.e. 10 seconds)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will fire in the given `timeInterval`, so not immediately. And when you set `repeats` to NO, it will not fire itself again, otherwise, it will send the first message after `timeInterval` seconds, then every `timeInterval` seconds.

Comment: thanks. What would be an option to fire immediately but still have an interval following? I guess I would just call the selector. But that could probably cause collisions on whery tight intervals, right?

Comment: I don't know if performSelector: will work just as a static message in code, so whether or not the method gets pushed on the stack and executed immediately, as normal, but I think it will. Maybe you don't even need performSelector: and call the message straight.

Comment: ah, yeah that's what I actually tried to say. Calling the method (which is specified as selector) just directly.

Comment: so whats the difference between the two:`+timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats` and `+ scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`

Comment: Please look at the documentation. The `scheduled` method also adds the timer to the default run loop, the other method leaves that to you. Adding a timer to a run loop is mandatory for it to actually be fired, so you'll probably want to use `scheduled`.